# Python find which string match with the random string

Tags: python, string, find, cpu-word

lets consider an example

```
words_list = ['apple', 'mango', 'orange']

origin = "acacpdqlep"
```

from "**a**cac**p**dq**lep**" the term 'apple' can be extracted

How can I solve this programatically without any library, some this like this

```
if words_list in origin:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Please help me in concept to achive this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `from collection import Counter` calculate the count of each letters in the word. Compare the count of each word in a word_list with origin word if count of each letter in word_list is less than that of origin You have your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
words_list = ['apple', 'mango', 'orange']
origin = "acacpdqlep"

def letters_in(word, origin):
    origin_chars = list(origin)
    for char in word:
        if char in origin_chars:
            origin_chars.remove(char)                
        else:
            return False
    return True

for word in words_list:
    print '{}: {}'.format(word, letters_in(word, origin))
```

Output:

```
apple: True
mango: False
orange: False
```